# Do I reference the session when making any db calls in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In this tutorial it says (http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html) to select all rows of an entity like:

```
s = products.select()
rs = s.execute()
```

I get an error saying:

**This select object is not bound and does not support direct execution ...**

Do I need to reference the session object?

I just want to get all rows in my products table (i've already mapped everything, and I already inserted thousands of rows so that part works)

Comment: It depends how `products` is mapped. Could you also provide relevant code? (products definition and mapping)

Comment: When you tried creating the session, did it work?  If not, what other errors did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that tutorial is built for SQLALchemy 0.2, it is likely that you aren't using that old of a version. In the latest documentation using the connection and passing the select statement to it is the preferred method. Try this instead:

```
query = users.select()
result = conn.execute(query)
```

Ref: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/sqlexpression.html#selecting